# rails server doesn't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed ruby and rails succesfully.
I use ruby 2.1.0 and rails 4.1.0
My O.S. is ubuntu 12.04

After creating a new rails application and set the current directory that I tried
to start the rails server (`~/my_app$ rails server`), but it gives the following error:

```
*/home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/uglifier-2.5.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/uglifier-2.5.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/my_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/my_app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/my_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/miguel/my_app/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /home/miguel/my_app/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'*
```

and the server doesn't run.

What is the matter?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to install a JS runtime

You have a couple of options

1. install NodeJS `sudo apt-get install nodejs`
2. add to your gemfile `gem 'therubyracer'`

[therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer)

Answer (score -1):

Rail's [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) uses the javascript runtime for converting coffeescript into javascript (and a few other miscellanous tasks).

For small/demo projects, or for projects that don't want to use coffeescript, you can turn off the asset pipeline by adding

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

to your `config/application.rb`